# prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator custom counters for functions

Tags: python, prometheus, fastapi, metrics, instrumentation

I am using the [prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator](https://pypi.org/project/prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator/) in order to instrument my fast api application.
Although I am able to get the metrics at the request level, I am facing issues when it comes to exposing counters with further granularity.

I have created a metric in this manner

```
@staticmethod
    def invalid_doc_type_counter():
        METRIC = Counter(
            "invalid_doc_type_count",
            "Number of times invalid doc type issue came up",
            labelnames=("handler",)
                         )
        METRIC.labels("info.modified_handler").inc()
```

And I am trying to call it in another function in this manner

```
        if not filtered_det:
            #Invalid doc type counter
            Counters.invalid_doc_type_counter()
            raise ValueError("Invalid Doc Type")
```

When I hit the `/metrics` endpoint, I get
`invalid_doc_type_count_total{handler="info.modified_handler"} 1.0` <---This value remains at one and doesn't change

The documentation doesn't exactly specify how to handle these kind of use-cases. For example: A route might have might internal function calls. The goal is create a counter for failures of each of those calls and expose them.